# Video not working on with swift code

Tags: ios, swift, video, swift3, avplayerviewcontroller

All this code features is a single button on a view controller. The button should play the video. Right now there is no error message in the code. All that happens is that the button is pressed and nothing happens. There is no error message. All I have is one view controller page. The code is listed below.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var moviePlayer: AVPlayerViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playLocalVideo()
}
func playLocalVideo(){

            if moviePlayer != nil {
                do {
                     let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "t", ofType: "mp4")

                    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)


                    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
                    let playViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

                     playViewController.player = player
                    self.present(playViewController, animated: true) {() -> Void in playViewController.player!.play()

                    }

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }}}}
```

Comment: Have you checked video added to target ?

Comment: Your  `moviePlayer` is nil and never goes inside `if moviePlayer != nil`.So instantiate it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
 import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let  moviePlayer =  AVPlayerViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        playLocalVideo()
    }




    func playLocalVideo(){

        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "t", ofType: "mp4"){
            let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)


            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)


            moviePlayer.player = player
            self.present(moviePlayer, animated: true) {
                self.moviePlayer.player!.play()
            }
        }

        else{
            print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
        }
    }


}
```

And make sure while adding video to target , it should not be the image like below one

[image]

and it should be like the below one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In playLocalVideo, `moviePlayer: AVPlayerViewController?` is not being initialized, it will be **nil**, so nothing happens when the button is pressed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

    ...
    ...

    func playLocalVideo(){
            if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "t", ofType: "mp4") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            moviePlayer.player = player
            present(moviePlayer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```